# Python turtle: problems with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pip, turtle-graphics

So I wanted to use the python package turtle, which uses the underlying package tkinter.
With this code:

```
import turtle
```

python raised an error which said, that the package tkinter was not found.
So I edited the turtle.py file and changed the

```
from tkinter import xyz
```

to

```
from tk import xyz
```

and at least the error was gone, but another appeared.
It is now saying

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'simpledialog' from 'tk' (C:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\tk\__init__.py)
```

I've updated pip and reinstalled both packages.
I'm using python 3.9.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
```

Or whichever type of simpledialog you want to make

Feel free to ask question in case of confusion.

Comment: I dont want to make any simpledialog. I want to use the turtle library and when I try to import turtle it throws this error. Thats why I changed the tkinter library-name in the turtle.py file